# How to make the text inside the facebook like button white?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook

I am using the facebook like button on a page with a red gradient background. I would like the text inside this share button to be white not the dark blue that it currently is (the "be the first of your friends to like this" text):

[image]

I'm not sure how to go about this though. This is the code used to generate the button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<current page's url here>" data-send="true" data-width="360" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>
```

The code generated according to firebug is this:

```
<div data-font="arial" data-show-faces="false" data-width="360" data-send="true" data-href="<current page's url here>" class="fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget">
    <span>
        <iframe scrolling="no" id="f29d650aad23b3a" name="fc2a4f4faf238e" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 29px; width: 360px;" title="Like this content on Facebook." class="fb_ltr" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=271291652883209&amp;channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df28525cd54eb78%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F<current page's url here>&amp;extended_social_context=false&amp;font=arial&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2F<current page's url here>%2Ftag%2Fzach-galifianakis&amp;layout=standard&amp;locale=en_US&amp;node_type=link&amp;sdk=joey&amp;send=true&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=360"></iframe>
    </span>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to make that text white?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook, how to change like button image?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4920945/facebook-how-to-change-like-button-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Facebooks TOS Item IV. 7. d. 
“You must not obscure elements of the Like button or Like box plugin.”
http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

If you go to this page you can make it dark. 
Under Color Scheme you can chose "dark".
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

Here is a blog entry where someone disguises the like button.
http://www.esrun.co.uk/blog/disguising-a-facebook-like-link/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to simply hide the like button and instead just create your own. Then you'd bind a click event on your custom button that simply triggers a click event on the actual, hidden Like button.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you try Anders solution first, as it may be the quickest and simpler solution for your situation, since you can freely change the background image.

But this article will tell you exactly how to even point a css file with your own rules for the facebook box. there's even a demo:
http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-add-a-custom-facebook-like-box-to-your-site

Good luck =)